# Find background-color of the appended td in a row using index of td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to find the background-color of the appended td in a row currently appending using Jquery but it's not working.

How to get the css of the td using index value.

This is I have tried so far:

```
while ($(row1).children('td:nth-child(' + startIndex + ')').css('background-color') == 'rgba(0,0,0,0)') {
    startIndex = startIndex + 1;
}
//Here row1 - is tr , startIndex - Index of td which I need to find css
```

Comment: "_it's not working_" How do you know? What goes wrong then?

Comment: the 'while loop" exits even though the condition satisfies.How to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't, the condition isn't satisfied ...

Comment: You already know the row and the index. What's the while loop for? Just do `$(row1).children('th:nth-child(' + startIndex + ')').css('background-color')`

Comment: I need to move index value left side one, If matches condition.How to do it? please give me suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

try this may this helpful & meet your requirement!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table-id tr").each(function () {
        if($(this).children('td:nth-child(' + startIndex + ')').css('background-color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)"){
          startIndex = startIndex + 1;
        }
    });
})
```

Note : some browser supports rgba(0, 0, 0, 0).